# How to return data before moving forward in object literal pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I have this code,

```
MyNameSpace.Crate = {
    init: function (crateID) {
        var crate = MyNameSpace.Crate.get(crateID);
        MyNameSpace.Crate.processData(crate);
        // do more with data
    },
    get: function (crateID) {
        var url = root + "Crate/";
        $.getJSON(url, {
            crateID: crateID
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            // return data
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            // do soemthing
        });;

    },
    processData : function(){
        // do something with data
    },
    so on..
}
```

What I want is to FIRST get data from `MyNameSpace.Crate.get(crateID)` only then move forward to `MyNameSpace.Crate.processData(crate);` and other methods. As you can see `get` method is async so I am not sure how can I force my code flow to get crate from get method before moving any forward.

**Edit**

I can call `processData` method in .done(... function but that is not I want to achieve, it will not let me follow object literal pattern, which is why question mentioned in comments is not helpful.

Comment: @JuicyScripter they are not using object literal pattern

Comment: The pattern is irrelevant to the solution - pass the function to execute upon completion of the request in the callback.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan pattern isn't irrelevant here, I am trying to implement separation of concerns and separate methods as you can see, all of the solutions to question you are saying it's duplicate of are irrelevant, as I am already using callbacks "done"..

Comment: Pass an anonymous function to the `get()` method to be executed within the `done()`. In that anonymous function can be placed any code you require for that specific instance of `MyNameSpace.Crate`. By callback I am not referring to the `done()` method of the deferred. If you read and understand the explanation of the problem in the question I linked I'm sure this will become much clearer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i find it difficult to understand code in words, can you point me to the exact answer I could follow from the old question my post is duplicate of, please ? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that question is like reading a book, even though i read it 10 times, it makes no sense to me, let me try once again